# Highlighting neighboring hexagons on mouseover

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hexagonal-tiles

I've been trying to port my love2D game into unity for the past day and I've come across one main issue at the moment: I can't replicate the neighbor highlighting.

The issue is:
If I go from hovering over one hexagon to another, if the hexagon I've gone to shares neighbors from the previous hexagon, those neighbors won't be highlighted.

Here's my code for highlighting the neighbors:

```
foreach(Tile tile in hex.neighbours){
    tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color=tile.data.Elements[tile.data.Element];
    if (on){    // are we highlighting?
        print("Highlighting..");
        if(tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color==tile.data.Elements[tile.data.Element] ){
            //if the color of the neighbors is the same as it's element's color(meaning it hasn't been highlighted yet), highlight it.
            print("changing color!");
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color=tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color+new Color32(20,20,20,0);
        }
    }
    else{
        //unhightlighting
        if(tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color!=tile.data.Elements[tile.data.Element]){
            //if the color of the neighbors isn't the same as it's element's color(meaning it's highlighted), unhighlight it.
            tile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color=tile.data.Elements[tile.data.Element];             
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm checking if I should highlight or unhighlight:

```
    foreach(KeyValuePair<GameObject,Hex> h in HexData){
        if (hovering==null && h.Value.hovering){
            h.Value.hovering=false;
            //if we're not hovering over anything and a hexagon still has it's neighbors highlighted, unhighlight it's neighbors
            if (h.Value.neighborsHighlighted==true){
                highlightNeighbors(false,h.Value);
                h.Value.neighborsHighlighted=false;
            }
        }
        if(!h.Value.hovering && h.Value.neighborsHighlighted){
            {
                //if a hexagon isn't being hovered over, but it's neighbors are still hightlighed, unhighlight them.
                highlightNeighbors(false,h.Value);
                h.Value.neighborsHighlighted=false;
            };
        }
        if (h.Value.hovering && h.Value.neighborsHighlighted==false){
            //if we're hovering over a hexagon and it's neighbors aren't highlighted, highlight them
            highlightNeighbors(true,h.Value);
            h.Value.neighborsHighlighted=true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by highlighting and unhighlighting in the bit of code where I change the .hovering property/variable

```
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.name.Contains("Hex"))
        {
            hovering=hit.collider.gameObject;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<GameObject,Hex> h in HexData){
                if (h.Key==hovering){
                    highlightNeighbors(true,h.Value);
                    h.Value.hovering=true;
                }
                else if(h.Key!=hovering && h.Value.hovering==true){
                    highlightNeighbors(false,h.Value);
                    h.Value.hovering=false;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if (hovering){
            hovering=null;
        }
    }
```